# How add special characters in WebTarget.queryParam name in client JavaEE 7

Tags: java, jax-rs, special-characters, urlencode, java-ee-7

I try make request using client library javax.ws.rs

I'm trying to add a parameter name containing characters [ and ] to query parameters, for encdoded special characters i am used URLEncoder.encode(). But after the request, the response contains data without this parameter, the server ignored this request parameter. I made a request on the command line using "curl" on purpose with an error in this parameter and got the same result as from the request in the application. The error is clearly in the encoded parameter name, but I don’t understand how to correctly add parameters containing special characters.

The Code:

```
    WebTarget webTarget = new Client().target(uri);
    String key = "filters[Time].Start";
    key = URLEncoder.encode(key,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

    String value = "2022-08-27+17:00:00";
    value = URLEncoder.encode(value,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    webTarget = webTarget.queryParam("per_page","10");
    webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(key,value);
    webTarget = webTarget.queryParam("order_by","time");

    invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

Result sout : filters%5BTime%5D.Start  2022-08-27%2B17%3A00%3A00

Comment: what I didn't unterstand in your question: did you try to use `curl` only to simulate an erroneous case of calling, or did you also try to use it to prove that the server accepts the requests as you wanted to send it with your client?

Comment: @cyberbrain, first, with the help of curl, I checked the correct operation of the server with the correct request and received the correct response, JSON with of the correct date (from query parameters).
Then I made another request with an error in the parameter name filters5BTime%5D.Start(i just deleted % after word 'filters') and received a JSON response with a different date. So I realized that the problem is in the parameter name

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the environment here to reproduce it, but did you also try to skip the URL encoding for key and/or value? You also could use a tool like Wireshark or https://mock-server.com to check what exactly happens to your parameters. (double encoding, skipping, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By advise @cyberbrain, i did checked my request in server by help 'tcpdump' utilite with key '-A'.

I did request by curl and after by my java application and compare data.

In my case problems was in value parametrs, my value equels "2022-08-27+17:00:00". After add in queryparametr this symbol '+' encoded to code '%2B' and this don't like my server. I just replaced symbol '+' to symbol space (code %20) in value ("2022-08-27 17:00:00"). After that i geted correct data from my server